# Regex para endereços (Ruas, Avenidas e Etc)

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso de um regex que pegue os casos que tem número no nome do endereço e também endereço normal. **O Número sempre termina depois do endereço.**

 Exemplo: R 25 de março 200. 

 Eu preciso do endereço que seria: R 25 de março

 E número do endereço: 200

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\D+");
match = regex.Match("R 25 de março 200");
if (match.Success) {
string endereco = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Porque o -1? gostaria de saber o motivo.

Comment: Qual é o padrão? o endereço sempre terminará com o número da casa?

Comment: Sim, sempre termina com um numero da casa.

Comment: Já tentou splitar por espaço em branco e pegar a ultima ocorrência?

Comment: Não, M. Bertolazo, eu necessito em regex mesmo.

Comment: Coloca um $ no final do seu regex e vê se é isso que você quer: `new Regex(@"\D+$");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar a regex:

```
([\w\W]+)\s(\d+)
```

Explicação:

```
Grupo 1: ([\w\W]+) -> pega qualquer caractere antes do último espaço
\s -> espaço separador, não pertence a nenhum grupo
Grupo 2: (\d+) -> pega somente números após o último espaço
```

Ficaria assim:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\w\W]+)\s(\d+)");
var match = regex.Match("R 25 de março 200");
if (match.Success) {
    string endereco = match.Groups["1"].Value;
    string numero = match.Groups["2"].Value;
}
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/r9hm9n)**

Comment: Muito obrigado, Resolveu minha duvida.